# События от клавиатуры

Tags: c#

Как задать движение окружности от стрелок клавиатуры? Необходимо, чтобы окружность двигалась после нажатий стрелок на клавиатуре.

Comment: Уточните, что вы хотите получить. Игрушку с управляемой картинкой?

Comment: выделяешь свой объект - вешаешь на него листенер - обрабатываешь...

Answer (score 1):

Нужно повесить обработчик слушатель на форму и в нем менять координаты объекта, который вы хотите перемещать по форме.

```
// Добавить обработчик
control.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnKeyDown);

// В обработчике изменить координаты объекта
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        positionX -= 1;
    if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        positionX += 1;
}
```

Если это WPF, можно менять координаты через связывание данных.

Comment: может быть ``KeyCode``, ``Keys.Left`` и ``Keys.Right``? [пруф](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern Int16 GetKeyState(Keys keys);

        byte[] bCharData = new byte[256];
        bool w = ((GetKeyState(Keys.W) & 256) == 256);
        if (w) Console.Write("w");
        bool s = ((GetKeyState(Keys.S) & 256) == 256);
        if (s) Console.Write("s");
        bool a = ((GetKeyState(Keys.A) & 256) == 256);
        if (a) Console.Write("a");
        bool d = ((GetKeyState(Keys.D) & 256) == 256);
        if (d) Console.Write("d");
```

Comment: Ну, разберёшься дальше.